# L'Hôpital's rule and Difference Quotients

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Consider the general difference quotient for a function $f(x)$ that is differentiable at $x = a$:

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$$

Since both the numerator and denominator of the difference quotient are differentiable and approach 0, it seems like we should be able to apply l'Hospital's rule, differentiating with respect to $x$:

\begin{align}
f'(a) & = \lim_{x \to a} \, \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \\
& = \lim_{x \to a} \, f'(x), \text{ given we fix $a$ and have assumed $f$ is differentiable}
\end{align}

But this seems to imply that $f'(x)$ is continuous or $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable at $x = a$.

I don't understand where this additional condition comes from: I suspect the problem may be in applying l'Hospital's rule (perhaps it's circular?). But to use l'Hospital's and know the limit existed, it was sufficient to assume $f(x)$ was differentiable at $x = a$. Nowhere did we have to make the assumption that the function be continuously differentiable.

I must be overlooking some small detail, but I just cannot put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you use LHR, you assume the quotient of derivatives has a limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vey nice case that shows us how important are assumptions. In De l'Hospital's theorem, we must assume that both the numerator and the denominator are differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$: this is much more than assuming the differentiability at $a$.
Bu what is even more important, is that this theorem states that IF
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f'(x) \quad\text{exists}
$$
THEN also
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \quad\text{exists and has the same value}.
$$
In other words, De l'Hospital's theorem applies only if $f'$ is a continuous function at $a$. We should not be surprised, since De l'Hospital's theorem cannot be as strong as the very definition of derivative.

Comment: Thanks! So basically to use l'Hospital's we needed to also know that f would be differentiable in the neighborhood of a, which amounts to saying it is continuously differentiable at a.

Comment: Well, the two statements are not really equivalent. Think of that old sufficient condition for differentiability: if $f$ is differentiable in a punctured neighborhood of a point $a$ and if $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists as a real number, then $f$ is differentiable also at $a$. The proof is a direct application of De l'Hospital's theorem (or even of the MVT), but what you actually show is that $f'$ can be continuously extended at $a$.